# Is it better to use @font-face or cufon rather than images?

Tags: font-face, cufon

I have a site that requires Trade Gothic. I'm wondering if it's better practice to use @font-face or cufon with a font that looks similar to Trade Gothic or just go the image route. Obviously, using images will *look* better but what is better practice? For example, is replacing header titles with images like below bad?

`<h2><span>title here</span></h2>`

```
span { display:none }
h2 { background:url(image.jpg);display:block;height:x;width:y }
```

Comment: Well, SEO is important. But is my example bad for SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the most obvious advantage that @font-face and cufon have against the image replacement method that you mention is that they generate your text dynamically and you don't have to create an image for each text that you want to replace.

Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692990/sifr-vs-cufon-vs-typeface-js

Comment: Yeah, I understand their purpose but I guess what I'm asking is, is it better to sacrifice your fonts looking a tad different than intended for the sake of seo. Or is using images for headers perfectly ok?

Comment: You must answer that question yourself, depending on the nature of your project. The image-replacement is SEO compatible, but you will have to replace each text manually, which is ok for a small presentational website but not, for example, for a social networking site.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the strictness of your requirement and browser support within your target audience, especially if you want to support mobile devices.

If using a similar-looking font is good enough, the requirement may really be a nice-to-have feature, so anything that degrades gracefully should work. @font-face seems the easiest to implement (just CSS and font files) and it doesn't require Flash or JavaScript (good for mobile users).  [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) is a great resource or you may even be able to create your own web font using a generator like [this one](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

You'll have to decide what works best for the majority of your audience and weigh in how flexible the requirement is. If you use a JavaScript-based solution and the audience has it disabled, is that a deal-breaker? Image replacement is not inherently bad, but it can be tedious to maintain if you have much content to worry about (especially if it also changes often).

Answer (score 1):

I use both.

I like to use Cufon for navigation and/or main heading elements, because I think it renders better (specifically in Windows).

For any sub-headers and other text, I use @font-face, so that users may select the text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently replacing header images with @font face, as they can load quicker, and text is always more SEO friendly, however you must be careful when doing this as this increases http requests which can then take longer to load. Also there are some legal issue as to which fonts can be used for web.

However it is especially ideal when no other font will do.

FYI browser support for @font face has been available since IE 4, as far as I know.